# Needing 2 different ID's from the same ID Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am pulling reports for my company and am needing to pull a specific report that I am having trouble with. We are using SQL Server 2012 and I am pulling the SQL reports.

What I need is to pull a simple report:

*Group Name, List of Members in the group; Supervisor of the group.*

However, the problem is that the supervisor as well as the members and the group name all come from one table in order to get the relevant information. Currently here is my SQL code below:

```
Use DATABASE
go

--   This is the select portion deciding the columns needed.    
select 
C.group_name
,C2.first_name
,C2.last_name

-- These are the tables that the query is pulling from.

FROM db..groups AS G
LEFT OUTER JOIN db..contact AS C
ON G.group_id=C.contact_id
INNER JOIN db..contact AS C2
ON G.member=C2.contact_id
go
```

This pulls the first portion:

*The group name, then the first name of a member in that group, and then the last name of a member in that group.*

However, I am having trouble getting the supervisor portion. This portion uses the table **db.contact** under the column **supervisor_id** as a foreign key. The **supervisor_id** uses the same unique id as the normal **contact_id**, but in the same table. Some contact_ids have supervisor_id's that are other contact_id's from the same table, hence the foreign key.

How can I make it so I can get the contact_id that is equal to the supervisor_id of the contact_id that is equal to the group_id?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the schema for groups and contact (right click on table and select Script to clipboard

Comment: Also, why are you joining group_id to contact_id? (G to C)?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick stab at this while we wait for details

You know you need groups and I'm assuming you don't care about Groups that have no members.  Thus Groups INNER JOINed to Contact. This generates your direct group membership. To get the supervisor, you then need to factor in the Supervisor on the specific Contact row.

You might not have a boss, or your boss might be yourself. It's always interesting to see how various HR systems record this. In my example, I'm assuming the head reports to no one instead of themselves.

```
SELECT
    G.group_name
,   C.first_name
,   C.last_name
    -- this may produce nulls depending on outer vs inner join below
,   CS.first_name AS supervisor_first_name
,   CS.last_name AS supervisor_last_name
FROM
    dbo.Groups AS G
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Contact AS C
        ON C.contact_id = G.member
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Contact AS CS
        ON CS.contact_id = C.supervisor_id;
```

Depending on how exactly you wanted that data reported, there are various tricks we could use to report that data. In particular, [GROUPING SETS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) might come in handy.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6b3e/5)